# GIN binding problems in GWTP application

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin

every one!
I'm having a compilation problem in my GWT app which is divided in 3 modules: 
App-core: containing the main classes without an entry point,
App-A and App-B: inherit from App-core, and containing there specific classes with an entry point in each submodule.

I'm using GIN to inject classes instances in every module:

in App-core:

```
public interface App-coreGinjector extends Ginjector {
EventBus getEventBus();
Provider<LoginPagePresenter> getLoginPagePresenter();
...
}

App-coreModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {

protected void configureCore() {
    install(new DefaultModule(App-corePlaceManager.class));
    bindConstant().annotatedWith(DefaultPlace.class).to(LoginPagePresenter.NAME_TOKEN);
    ...
    bind(AuthenticationManager.class).to(AuthenticationManagerImpl.class);
    bindPresenter(LoginPagePresenter.class, LoginPagePresenter.MyView.class,
                  LoginPageView.class, LoginPagePresenter.MyProxy.class);
 }
```

in App-A:

```
@GinModules({ App-AModule.class })
public interface App-AGinjector extends App-coreGinjector {

MyApp-AScreen getMyApp-AScreen();
...
}

public class App-AModule extends App-coreModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {

    configureCore();
            ...
            //Here we bind the App-A classes inheriting from App-core classes 
            bind(App-coreScreenManager.class).to(App-AcreenManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
            ...
            //Here we bind the specific App=A classes
    }
```

And we do the same thing in App-B

The maven compilation is successful for the App-A, but it fail for the App-B, with this message:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'C:\workspace\App-core\client\gin\App-coreGinjectorImpl.java'
[ERROR] Line 790:  Rebind result 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManager' must be a class
[ERROR] Line 818:  Rebind result 'lu.sfeir.grh.client.authentication.AuthenticationManager' must   be a class
[ERROR] Line 1047:  Rebind result 'lu.sfeir.grh.client.login.LoginPagePresenter.MyView' must be a class
[ERROR] Line 2359:  Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus' cannot be abstract
[ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
```

So the weird part int all this is that this error come from the shared module between these two submodules, witch is the binding of the LoginPagePresenter and the AuthentificationManager, but we have this compilation error just in one sub module.
So if someone had this king of problems I'm waiting for his precious help ^^

Ah! if you want some precisions , don't be shy!!

Comment: A few questions (this is tough without having all the code to look over, GWTP has a lot of files that it breaks this all down into), what are you importing for the EventBus, is it com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus? Also your PlaceManager implementation should subclass PlaceManagerImpl. If you can bundle up the code I should be able to get this sorted out for you, there's a lot that can go wrong, and it's not easy to know where to begin looking from just what's here. The way I approach this is to simplify, first remove everything but the EventBus and the PlaceManager, and see if you can get

Answer (score 2):

In GWTP 0.7 and all EventBus instances are changed from

```
    com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus;
    to 
    com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus
```

If you are using GWTP 0.6 you have to change them back...